# Doubly linked list Fortran. Print from tail to head.

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to print out a doubly linked list. I am able to get the list to print from head to tail. However when I try to print from tail to head only the head prints. This is the last part of the code. I have included the link list code. Any suggestions?

```
*INPUT UP TO EOF
   NULLIFY(HEAD,TAIL)
   DO WHILE(.TRUE.)
       READ(1,*,END=999)NAMEIN
       READ(1,*,END=999)AGEIN

*INITIALIZE THE POINTERS TO NULL
      NULLIFY(CURRENT)
      ALLOCATE(CURRENT)
      CURRENT%PERSON = NAMEIN
      CURRENT%AGE = AGEIN 
*IF THERE IS NOT AT LEAST ONE NODE

      IF(.NOT.ASSOCIATED(HEAD))THEN
          HEAD => CURRENT
          TAIL => CURRENT
          NULLIFY(HEAD%NEXT,HEAD%PREV)

*IF THE CURRENT IS LAST NODE      
      ELSE
*PLACE AT END OF LIST

          TAIL%NEXT =>CURRENT
         CURRENT%PREV=>TAIL
          NULLIFY(CURRENT%NEXT)

*CHANGE TAIL POINTER TO NEW END
          TAIL => CURRENT
          NULLIFY(CURRENT%NEXT)
          NULLIFY(CURRENT%PREV)
     END IF    
  END DO

999    CONTINUE

*PRINT FROM HEAD TO TAIL      
*POINT TO THE BEGINNING
  NULLIFY(TEMP)   
  TEMP => HEAD
*PRINT EACH NODE
  PRINT *,'-----PRINTING fROM HEAD TO TAIL-----'
  DO WHILE(ASSOCIATED(TEMP))
      PRINT 5,TEMP%PERSON
      PRINT 10,TEMP%AGE
      TEMP => TEMP%NEXT
  END DO

*PRINT FROM TAIL TO HEAD      
*POINT TO THE BEGINNING   
*PRINT EACH NODE
  CURRENT => TAIL
  PRINT *,'-----PRINTING fROM TAIL TO HEAD------'
  DO WHILE(ASSOCIATED(cCURRENT))
      PRINT 5,CURRENT%PERSON
      PRINT 10,CURRENT%AGE
      CURRENT => CURRENT%PREV
  END DO
```

Comment: Can you please turn caps lock off when you write English text?

Comment: @Barry: SPECIAL FORTRAN KEYBOARD

Comment: its a practice problem i am working on to study for my next exam.

Answer (score 1):

You nullify the `PREV` pointer thus destroying the back link:

```
*CHANGE TAIL POINTER TO NEW END
          TAIL => CURRENT
          NULLIFY(CURRENT%NEXT)
          NULLIFY(CURRENT%PREV) <--- THE PROBLEM LIES HERE
```